# InnoDB secondary index includes value instead of pointer to PK, how is it enough?

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, myisam

I am reading `Effective Mysql - Optimizing Mysql Statements` and in `chapter 3` there was this explanation:

> The secondary indexes in InnoDB use the B-tree data structure; however, they differ from the MyISAM implementation. **In InnoDB, the secondary index stores the physical value of the primary key.** In MyISAM, the secondary index stores a pointer to the data that contains the primary key value.
>
> This is important for two reasons. First, the size of secondary indexes in InnoDB can be much larger when a large primary key is defined—for example when your primary key in InnoDB is 40 bytes in length. As the number of secondary indexes increase, the comparison size of the indexes can become significant. The second difference is that the secondary index now includes the primary key value and ***is not required as part of the index.*** This can be a significant performance improvement with table joins and covering indexes.

There are many questions that come to my mind, mostly due to lack of understanding of what author is trying to convey.

1. It is unclear what the author means in the second difference in
   second paragraph. What ***is not required as part of index*** anymore?
2. Does InnoDB secondary index B-tree only store PK value or PK value
   and Pointer to it? or PK Value and pointer to data row?
3. What kind of performance improvement would there be due to the storage method (2nd question's answer)?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024226/mysql-difference-in-index-usage-between-myisam-and-innodb) question contains an example and also an answer. He explains how it contains PK value, but what I am still not understanding is,

To complete the join, if the pointer is not there in the secondary index and only the value, wont MySQL do a full index scan on Primary Key index with that value from secondary index? How would that be efficient than having the pointer also?

Comment: Q1:  Yeah, that is cryptic.  I address it from a different point of view; I hope my phrasing is less cryptic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The secondary index is an indirect way to access the data. Unlike the primary (clustered) index, when you traverse the secondary index in InnoDB and you reach the leaf node you find a primary key **value** for the corresponding row the query is looking for. Using this value you traverse the primary index to fetch the row. This means **2 index look ups in  InnoDB**.
For MyISAM because the leaf of the secondary node is a pointer to the actual row you only require 1 index lookup.

The secondary index is formed based on certain attributes of your table that are not the PK. Hence the PK is not required to be part of the index by definition. Whether it is (InnoDB) or not (MyISAM) is implementation detail with corresponding performance implications.
Now the approach that InnoDB follows might at first seem inefficient in comparison to MyISAM (2 lookups vs 1 lookup) but it is not because the primary index is kept in memory so the penalty is low.
But the advantage is that InnoDB can split and move rows to optimize the table layout on inserts/updates/deletes of rows without needing to do any updates on the secondary index since it does not refer to the affected rows directly

Comment: Few questions, slightly tangential.

1. What exactly is meant by "index is kept-in/managed in-memory" ? It only exists in-memory or a cache of index in disk is in-memory?
2. What happens to those items in-memory when server is restarted? Or in worst case plug is pulled while it is running?

Comment: @ArunRajagopal: The index is stored on disk but it will be loaded and kept in memory for efficiency. All the data are backed by disk and updated with ACID properties so when the power is lost the data are still on disk

Comment: @Cratylus - _Blocks_ are _cached_ in memory; _indexes_ are not _kept_ in memory.

Comment: @RickJames: May be my terminology is not accurate. As far as I know MySQL will try to use as much of the RAM as possible. And the corresponding data structure for the index file will be loaded in memory so it won't access the file each time

Comment: @Cratylus - The entire index is not loaded.  Each block, as it is requested, is loaded and stays in RAM until it gets bumped out.  Typically, pieces of a table and pieces of each index are sitting in the buffer pool.  There is no attempt to _initially_ load into memory "the corresponding data structure for the index file", only pieces of it _as needed_.  A 16KB block is the unit of fetching.

Answer (score 2):

**Basics..**

MyISAM's PRIMARY KEY and secondary keys work the same. -- Both are BTrees in the `.MYI` file where a "pointer" in the leaf node points to the `.MYD` file.

The "pointer" is either a byte offset into the `.MYD` file, or a record number (for `FIXED`).  Either results in a "seek" into the `.MYD` file.

InnoDB's data, including the columns of the `PRIMARY KEY`, is stored in one BTree ordered by the PK.

This makes a PK lookup slightly faster.  Both drill down a BTree, but MyISAM needs an extra seek.

Each InnoDB secondary key is stored in a separate BTree.  But in this case the leaf nodes contain any extra columns of the PK.  So, a secondary key lookup first drills down that BTree based on the secondary key.  There it will find all the columns of both the secondary key and the primary key.  *If* those are all the columns you need, this is a "covering index" for the query, and nothing further is done.  (Faster than MyISAM.)

But usually you need some other columns, so the column(s) of the PK are used to drill down the data/PK BTree to find the rest of the columns in the row.  (Slower than MyISAM.)

So, there are *some* cases where MyISAM does less work; *some* cases where InnoDB does less work.  There are a lot of other things going on; InnoDB is winning many comparison benchmarks over MyISAM.

**Caching...**

MyISAM controls the caching of 1KB index blocks in the key_buffer.  Data blocks are cached by the Operating System.

InnoDB caches both data and secondary index blocks (16KB in both cases) in the buffer_pool.

"Caching" refers to swapping in/out blocks as needed, with roughly a "least recently used" algorithm.

No BTree is loaded into RAM.  No BTree is *explicitly* kept in RAM.  Every block is requested as needed, with the *hope* that it is cached in RAM.  For data and/or index(es) smaller than the associated buffer (key_buffer / buffer_pool), the BTree *may happen* to stay in RAM until shutdown.

The source-of-truth is on disk.  (OK, there are complex tricks that InnoDB uses with log files to avoid loss of data when a crash occurs before blocks are flushed to disk.  That cleanup automatically occurs when restarting after the crash.)

**Pulling the plug..**

MyISAM:
Mess #1:  Indexes will be left in an unclean state.  `CHECK TABLE` and `REPAIR TABLE` are needed.
Mess #2:  If you are in the middle of `UPDATEing` a thousand rows in a single statement, some will be updated, some won't.

InnoDB:
As alluded to above, InnoDB performs things *atomically*, even across pulling the plug.  No index is left mangled.  No `UPDATE` is left half-finished; it will be `ROLLBACKed`.

**Example..**

Given

```
columns a,b,c,d,e,f,g
PRIMARY KEY(a,b,c)
INDEX(c,d)
```

The BTree leaf nodes will contain:

MyISAM:
for the PK:  `a,b,c,pointer`
for secondary:   `c,d,pointer`

InnoDB:
for the PK:  `a,b,c,d,e,f,g` (the entire row is stored with the PK)
for secondary:   `c,d,a,b`

Comment: Let's say primary key is (a,b,c) and secondary key is (c,d), so If I udnerstood correctly

InnoDB Primary key -> (pointer, a,b,c), Secondary (c,d,a,b,c).
MyISAM  Primary key -> (pointer, a,b, c), Secondary -> (pointer, c, d)

Am I right?

Comment: @MangatRaiModi - InnoDB has no "pointers".  There is no need to repeat `c`.  See my added Example.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I am not even more confused. I thought that leaf ode contains a pointer to  rest of the rows, called rowid -> https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_optop.htm#TGSQL232
https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/primary-keys

Comment: Actually on reading more, innodb uses clustered index on  primary keys, in that case you are  right :)
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html

Comment: @MangatRaiModi - Do not confuse "Oracle" database with "MySQL", in spite of MySQL being owned by Oracle.  The two implementations are quite different.  Oracle's dates back to the '70s, I think.  In the '90s one guy invented MyISAM to form the basis of MySQL.  Soon after, InnoDB was invented independently by another guy in about 2000.  It was then folded into MySQL and has now all-but-replaced MyISAM.

Comment: When there was only MyISAM, was it even used as widely as now? I am asking this because, wikipedia says MyISAM is a non-transactional engine. I assume that means, there is no commit/rollback feature. How did organisations implement atomic use cases without transaction capabilities in database?

Comment: @ArunRajagopal - It's hard to say.  MySQL, for a long time, defaulted to MyISAM.  _Most_ users simply use the defaults.  Gradually, users moved to InnoDB, but now that the default is InnoDB, almost everyone uses that engine.  Ditto for `CHARACTER SET` latin1, then utf8, then utf8mb4.

Comment: I've been using MyISAM since before InnoDB was added.  So, I still have detailed knowledge of MyISAM.  It had `LOCK TABLES` and `GET_LOCK`, with which you could crudely simulate transactions; perhaps some people did that.  MySQL is often used for web pages, for which transactions are (mostly) not important.

Comment: I think using "page" instead of "block" will be better.